# How can i test ember shortcuts with qunit

Tags: testing, ember.js, qunit

I am trying to test my ember application. There are shortcuts defined at my routes and everything works fine.
But i have no idea how to test these scenarios with qunit?

```
App.BaseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  shortcuts: {
          'alt+a': 'gotoArticles',
          'alt+p': 'gotoPhotos',
          'alt+t': 'gotoTests'
      },
      actions: {
        gotoArticles: function() {
          console.log('alt + a was pressed, --> articles');
          this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('articles');
        },
        gotoPhotos: function() {
          console.log('alt + p was pressed --> photos');
          this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('photos');
        },
        gotoTests: function() {
          console.log('alt + t was pressed --> tests');
          this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('testability');
        }
      }
    });
```

The question is how can i test the defined shortcuts with qunit?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do an integration test where you insert the view that's backed by `BaseRoute` then you can trigger an event on the element.

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; // # Some key code value
$("myelementintheview").trigger(e);
```